# MSB and LSB in floating point number

Tags: arithmetic, floating-point

What is MSB and LSB in significant of a floating point number? If I have a significant for example 0011010000 (half-precision) but 1. bit is implicit what is MSB: 0 or 1? In this case LSB is 0, because it is on the end of significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the whole floating point number the MSB is a sign bit and LSB is in the mantisa (last bit).

In all floating point formats with exception of 10 byte IEEE real the mantissa MSB of normalised number is not stored because it is implicitly set to $1$ (and used in calculations).

So in the case of your significand (mantissa) $0011010000$ the MSB is $1$ (implicit) and LSB is $0$ (explicit).

Comment: ... unless the biased exponent is 0 (denormalised number), then the implicit first bit of the mantissa is 0 in IEEE 754 32 and 64 bit format.